# Не наследуется прототип массива js

Tags: javascript, классы, наследование, prototype

Изучаю прототипное наследование js и столкнулся с проблемой.
Вот это работает:

```
class figure{
  constructor(){
    this.length = 0;
  }

}

figure.prototype.__proto__ = Object.create(Array.prototype);

let f = new figure();
f.push(3);
f.push(9);
console.log(f.join(','));
```

Поразмыслив решил перенести строку с заданием `__proto__` в тело класса( инициализируя в конструкторе класса).
Перенес, и получил вот такой код:

```
class figure{
  constructor(){
    this.length = 0;
    this.prototype.__proto__ = Object.create(Array.prototype)
  }

}

let f = new figure();
f.push(3);
f.push(9);
console.log(f.join(','));
```

Но он выдает ошибку, что не может присвоить свойство `__proto__` так-как оно `undefine`. Вопрос, почему возникает эта ошибка, как это работает ( ведь по идее `__proto__` должно быть не `undefine`) и как её решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> почему возникает эта ошибка

Потому что в этом месте

```
this.prototype.__proto__ = Object.create(Array.prototype)
```

`this` не то, что Вы думаете.

> как её решить

Использовать первый вариант кода. Изменять прототип создаваемого объекта в конструкторе, во-первых, слишком поздно (по крайней мере, для первого экземпляра этого типа), во-вторых, приводит к выполнению одного и того же кода (с одним и тем же результатом) при создании каждого нового объекта этого типа.

Comment: Про слишком поздно не понял, а про один и тот же результат догадка. Имелось ввиду, что для каждого нового объекта в `__proto__` будет храниться что-то типа ссылки на массив, но не на один и тотже, а на множество ( так-как каждая генерация объекта будет генерировать новый объект массива). Я правильно понял?